# 2D array help - multiplying a negative number

Tags: java, arrays, loops

### The error message is - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2

I am passing a 2d array into a method and the multiplying the values inside the array by 2. here is the method below.

it works correctly when I pass in the first array from main but not the second - these are also shown below the method code

does anyone have an idea how to amend this error? I also cannot hard code the loop iterations etc

```
int setuparray2 [][] = new int [][] {{4, 5},{6, 9} };                               
int setuparray3 [][] = new int [][] {{4, 6, 3},{-1,9,-5}};

scalarMultiplication(2,setuparray1);
scalarMultiplication(2,setuparray3);


public static void scalarMultiplication( int factor, int[][] a)
{   
    //creates a new array to hold the multiplied value
  int multiplyArray [][] = new int [a.length][a.length];

  for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
    {   
    //multiplys each element in the array by the factor     
    multiplyArray[i][j] = a[i][j] * factor;                                     
    }
  }
  //prints the array with the results
  printArray(multiplyArray);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when creating `multiplyArray` you do not reserve enough space.

Instead of:

```
int multiplyArray [][] = new int [a.length][a.length];
```

Write:

```
int multiplyArray [][] = new int [a.length][a[0].length];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing it in wrong way, below should be the correct way

```
 int multiplyArray [][] = new int [2][3];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the challenge we were set involved not "hard wiring" the code, and I felt that crossed that line really. if I am honest it was vague instructions form our tutor, thanks though for the response/